# (Java) How can I print an object's information when the object is in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, printing

I have an ArrayList in main and I have a class with a constructor inside it and a method to print the data. I add a new object with new information, when called, and adds it to the ArrayList to keep it in one place. What I'm having a hard time is the syntax to print the information. I tried it with a regular array but I need to use ArrayList. I need to be able to get the index of a specific object, and print that object's information. For example, the code below the last couple lines:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class student{

    String name;
    int age;
    int birthYear;

    public student(String name, int age, int birthYear){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }
    
    public void printStudentInformation(){
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(age);
        System.out.println(birthYear);
    }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList listOfObj = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList names = new ArrayList();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

            System.out.println("New Student Information:"); // Three student's information will be saved
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            int age = sc.nextInt();
            int birthYear = sc.nextInt();

            student someStudent = new student(name, age, birthYear);
            listOfObj.add(someStudent);
            names.add(name);
        }

        System.out.println("What student's information do you wish to view?");
        for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++){
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ") " + names.get(i)); // Prints all students starting from 1
        }
        int chosenStudent = sc.nextInt(); // Choose a number that correlates to a student
        
        // Should print out chosen student's object information
        listOfObj.get(chosenStudent).printStudentInformation(); // This is incorrect, but I would think the syntax would be similar?
        
    }
}
```

Any help or clarification is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your definition of `listOfObj` from:

```
ArrayList listOfObj = new ArrayList();
```

to:

```
ArrayList<student> listOfObj = new ArrayList<>();
```

The first will will create a `ArrayList` of `Object` class objects.

The second will create a `ArrayList` of `student` class objects.

Few more problems in your code:

1. Since you are reading name using `nextLine`, you may need to skip a new line after reading the birth year like:

```
...
int birthYear = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();  // Otherwise in the next loop iteration, it will skip reading input and throw some exception
...
```

2. You select an option for the student to display, but that option is 1 indexed and `ArrayList` stores 0 indexed, so you should change the line to `sc.nextInt() - 1`:

```
int chosenStudent = sc.nextInt() - 1; // Choose a number that correlates to a student
```

3. `Scanner` may throw exception in case you enter, for example, a string instead of an int. So make sure you are handling exceptions properly using `try-catch` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

- You change the ArrayList defination and add toString() in your studen
  class.
- And to print all the student object insted of using for loop use just
  one sop.

EX:-

```
import java.util.*;

class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int birthYear;

    public Student() {
        super();
    }

    public Student(String name, int age, int birthYear) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getBirthYear() {
        return birthYear;
    }

    public void setBirthYear(int birthYear) {
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [age=" + age + ", birthYear=" + birthYear + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

}

public class DemoArrayList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = scan.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            scan.nextLine();
            String name = scan.nextLine();
            int age = scan.nextInt();
            int birthYear = scan.nextInt();
            list.add(new Student(name, age, birthYear));
        }

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

O/P:-

```
2
joy 
10
2003
jay
20
2005
[Student [age=10, birthYear=2003, name=joy], Student [age=20, birthYear=2005, name=jay]]
```

Comment: Hi, can you edit your answer and add some code as well so that OP can understand it better?

Comment: ok just wait some times

Comment: now see this code.